# How to combine table column field to single column in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to combine table column field to single column in kendo-grid

```
  { field: 'name', title: 'Name' },
  { field: 'address', title: 'Address'},
  { field: 'phoneNumber', title: 'Phone Number' },
  { field: 'remarks', title: 'Remarks' },
  { command: ['edit', 'destroy'] }];
```

field: 'address' is an object.

address: {
blockNo: 'xx',
city: 'Singapore',
country: 'Singapore',
floorNo: 'xx',
id: 'xx',
zipCode: 'xxxxx',
streetName: 'xx',
unitNo: 'xx',
}

So, I need to combine to show in a single column in kendo-grid.

Eg. Blk-xx, #xx-xx, Singapore, xxxxx -> in a single column.

Comment: I got correct answer from my colleague :)

Answer is:
`
{ field: 'address', title: 'Address', template: 'BLK-#=address.blockNo+", "+address.streetName+", \\#"+address.floorNo#'} ,etc..
`
Thank you so much,..
I'm just add comment for knowledge sharing.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got correct answer from my colleague :)

Answer is:

```
var schema = [
      { field: 'name', title: 'Name' },
      { field: 'address', title: 'Address', template: 'BLK-#=address.blockNo+", "+address.streetName+", \\#"+address.floorNo+"-"+address.unitNo+ ", S-"+address.pinCode+", "+address.city+", "+address.country#'},
      { field: 'billingAddress', title: 'Billing Address', template: 'BLK-#=billingAddress.blockNo+", "+billingAddress.streetName+", \\#"+billingAddress.floorNo+"-"+billingAddress.unitNo+ ", S-"+billingAddress.pinCode+", "+billingAddress.city+", "+billingAddress.country#'},
      { field: 'phoneNo', title: 'Phone Number'},
      { field: 'fax', title: 'Fax'},
      { field: 'email', title: 'Email'},
      { field: 'contactPerson', title: 'Contact Person'},
      { field: 'remarks', title: 'Remarks' },
      { command: ['edit', 'destroy'] }];
```

Eg: BLK-xx, xx Street, #XX-XX, S-XXXXX, xxx, xxx

Thank you so much,..
I'm just add answer for knowledge sharing.. :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to use an external template or function to do this as well (which is my preferred solution as it is easier to maintain)

I have adapted a demo I used on a previous answer to highlight the method which may be of use.

[Templating Address Object](http://dojo.telerik.com/AVeBU/4)

All I have done is `extract` out the templating into a function like so:

```
 function generateAddress(data) {
   var retString = '';

   if (data !== undefined && data !== 'undefined' && data !== null) {
     retString += '<p><strong>Block No:</strong> ' + data.blockNo +
       '<br/><strong>Street Name:</strong>' + data.streetName +
       '<br/><strong>Floor No:</strong>' + data.floorNo +
       '<br/><strong>City:</strong>' + data.city +
       '<br/><strong>Zip Code::</strong>' + data.zipCode +
       '<br/><strong>Country:</strong>' + data.country + '</p>';
   } else {
     retString = '<p>N/A</p>';
   }


   return retString;
 }
```

Then change the template signature in you column to something like this:

```
{field: "address", width:"200px", title:"Address",
  template:"#=generateAddress(data.address)#" }
```

This way we just pass in the object to the function and any changes required can be performed in the function, **Note:** useful if you are using this in a lot of places within your code.

It also performs a simple check to see if the item exists and if it doesn't then it puts a place holder piece of text in its place.

I have also added in loading from an `external` template for you to view as well.

Personally I prefer the first option but these are some alternative approaches for you to look at in the future.

NB: Glad your colleague managed to help you with this issue.

Comment: Yes, bro.. Thanks for your suggestion.. bro